# Publish Subscribe Content Notifications

Tags: alfresco, publish-subscribe

I came across this site in alfresco discussing publish/subscribe notifications within alfresco and was wondering if there were any progress on it or someone had created an add-on

- http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Publish_Subscribe_Content_Notifications

Only type of notification I've read thus far from the wiki or forums is email or using rss feeds. The CMIS specifications does not encompass this and alfresco web services does not include any such methods.

We have several web applications that need to download content once a document has been uploaded and transformed in alfresco. I could develop an action to push the documents to the appropriate app, but that would require me to know every endpoint. At this point there are only 3 application but there are requirements to add additional ones in the future. Having a publisher/subscriber model would make the solution more scalable and easy maintenance in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you wrote a custom action that adds a message to a queue. You could have the queue/topic name configurable so that when someone configures a rule on a folder, they can specify which queue to put the message on. Your apps can then subscribe to the queue and act appropriately.

You could also do something similar as a step in a workflow.

Maybe the message would be something simple like the nodeRef or the CMIS object ID.

Comment: I'm not much of an alfresco expert, but does alfresco have a queue api that can be referenced externally. From my understanding it is used internally for workflows.

I saw some forums discussion about this: https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=18975, but not sure if this made it into production or not.

Comment: I was thinking you'd either already have a queue implementation you could call or you'd be willing to set one up for this purpose.